# ag-grid: Need to aggregate multiple fields into a table within a cell

Tags: ag-grid

I'm wondering what the best practice is for displaying a table (with data from multiple `fields`) within a cell in `ag-grid`?

I think I can get it to work with formatting the entire table as an html string and passing that to the grid as the `field` and using a `cellRenderer`, however I'd rather not have that kind of view logic on the server-side.

I'd really like for the column definition to be able to take in more than one field, but it doesn't seem like that's possible.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you just trying to concatenate the values together into a string, or are you trying to display icons/images/etc.? If you just want strings then you can use the `valueGetter` function from the `ColDef`.

Answer (score 13):

You can define a `valueGetter` for the desired column in column def.
Here is a sample -

```
valueGetter: 
function sumField(params) {
          return params.data.a + params.data.b
}
```

[Value getters example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/#example-getters-and-formatters)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was after. I'm using a server-side grid model, so my "field" property in the ColDef is used to construct my GraphQL query, so here I can put "property.subProperty1,property.subProperty2" and then the valueGetter can extract both values from the result.

Comment: it works. it should be the accepted answer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your `ColDef` for the column, you can pass `data` and then destructure the values you're looking for off of that object, which comes through `props` in ag-grid.

For example...

In your `ColDef` array:

```
{
  field: 'data',
  headerName: 'Name',
  cellRendererFramework: NameDescriptionRenderer
}
```

Then, in your `NameDescriptionRenderer`:

```
export default class NameDescriptionRenderer extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    const { description, name } = this.props.data;
    return <React.Fragment>{`${name}: ${description}`}</React.Fragment>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function fullNameGetter(params) {
    return params.data.Title + ' ' + params.data.FirstName + ' ' + params.data.MiddleName + ' ' + params.data.LastName;
  }

.....
    {
      headerName: 'Full Name',
      field: 'Title&FirstName&MiddleName&LastName',
      filter: true,
      width: 225,
      valueGetter: fullNameGetter,
    },
```

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer! Do keep in mind that you add some details about what you fixed or why it is right. It helps users understand what is going on, rather than just being served the answer. Consider this an absolute rule for all your answers here.