# Ag-grid: Is there a way to add a custom filter to default filters

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to add a custom filter of using string similarity algorithm to the default text filters. Is there any way to do it?

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: "Make",
          field: "make",
          sortable: true,
          filter: true,
          checkboxSelection: true,
        },
        ...
      ],
       ...
    }
  }
}
```

In the code above, if I give `true` for the filter of `Make` column, the full list of default text filters are presented. But if I add `filterParams.filterOptions` as below

```js
...
this.state = {
  columnDefs: [
    {
       headerName: "Make",
       field: "make",
       sortable: true,
       filter: "agTextColumnFilter", 
       filterParams: {
         filterOptions: [
           "similarTo",
           {
              displayKey: "similarTo",
              displayName: "similar to",
              test: function (filterValue, cellValue) {
                           ...
                   return stringSimilarity > 0.8;
              }
            }
            ...]
         }
      }
      ... ]
}
```

Only "similarTo" filter is on the list of filters. 
Is there any way to add this custom filter to the default text filters, including `contains`, `not contains`, `equals`, `not equals`, `starts with`, and `ends with`.

Comment: Use valueGetter in your column Def! See Example below.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866364/ag-grid-need-to-aggregate-multiple-fields-into-a-table-within-a-cell

Comment: I faced same issue with Angular. I bought licence from Ag-Grid and I sent a message for this issue then there is no reply. Ag-Grid has similiar annoying restrictions. Finally I will never use Ag-grid again and I will never recommend this worlds worst grid :)

Comment: I just saw the comments. Thanks for your comments guys. I solved above issue by adding ```contains```, ```notContains```, ```equals```, ```not equals```, ```starts with```, and ```ends``` in the filterOptions. For those default text filters, adding their names was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ag grid comes up with a solution to add custom filters.

These documents are enough to understand how we can implement them.

DocumentLink : https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-provided-simple/#custom-filter-options